# Problem with running my flutter code and opening emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/flutter ( 6139): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter ( 6139): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(462)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter ( 6139): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(669)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

I Keep getting this error when I run my code. Please show me instructions to solve this problem!

I have tried many ways flutter clean and Flutter run, clean pub cache and pub cache get, pub cache fix, nearly everythig.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen when we don't have the main method.

You might check if the code below already exist:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Note: `MyApp` is your main class.

Comment: I have tried it before but its not working! is there any other possible ways to solve it?

Comment: you may take a look at this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116527